# Image class not found when using Intervention

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, intervention

I have installed Laravel 5.2 and Intervention, this is now in the composer.json file in the project.

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
        "intervention/image": "^2.3"
    },
```

After reading tutorials, it mentions an Image.php file that should be in the config folder inside the project once you have installed Intervention. I believe I have installed Intervention correctly but when I try to use the Intervention functions it does not work.

When I try to use this line of code I get this error

```
$resizedImg = Image::make($path)->resize(200,200);

C:\xampp\htdocs\socialNet\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php line 738:
```

Class image does not exist

and in the file I am using this function I include this Use statement

```
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image as Image;
```

Comment: Did you register it in your application as a new service?
http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation#laravel

Comment: @JhonnyWalker Yes, I followed these instructions and register the application as a new service

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your app.php Add this in your `aliases`:

```
'Image' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class,
```

and in your `providers`

```
Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class,
```

Don't forget to do `php artisan config:cache` after this.

Comment: Thanks!! I had the aliases and providers added but I had not run config:cache and the error is now gone

Comment: Yes thats the problem. Thats why in development I don't cache the config. Run `php artisan config:clear` once and you will never run into such problems.

Comment: thank you man!!!! you literally saved my life. all i needed to do is php artisan config:clear

Answer (score 1):

First, you can use composer :

```
composer require intervention/image
```

Then declare it on app.php :

```
'providers' => [
    // ...
    Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class,
]
```

Then, still on app.php on 'aliases' declare it :

```
'aliases' => [
    // ...
    'Image' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class,
]
```

Hope it will help

Comment: Thanks, it's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you've followed the tutorial here: http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation#laravel And done everything as described, finally generate all the new classes with the composer command: `composer dump-autoload`. This will autoload your new facade. After this you can import the Image facade simply by `use Image;` in the class you wish to use the facade in.

Answer (score 0):

if you have file in modal or controller which filename does not match with class name or name space error in any file then you will not be able to resolve this issue as i have Userold.php was givng me ps-4 error and due to this my any operation was incomplete and i was getting `Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class,` first resolve it if anybody have then perform next operation.