# heroku return error 500 when i create an user with my register

Tags: laravel, heroku

i deploy my site and near to everything work, except my register, i used Laravel for my site, in local it's good but with heroku when i submit my form i have an error 500 and my user isn't created in my DB.

My logs :

```
2020-04-16T17:14:22.342187+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/register" host=born.herokuapp.com request_id=66c725dd-3a39-4017-b023-2659d4b7f208 fwd="86.68.15.24" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30002ms status=500 bytes=3215 protocol=http

2020-04-16T17:14:22.333083+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-16 17:14:22] production.ERROR: Class 'Intervention\Image\Facades\Image' not found {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Class 'Intervention\\Image\\Facades\\Image' not found at /app/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php:90)

2020-04-16T17:14:22.333104+00:00 app[web.1]: [stacktrace]

2020-04-16T17:14:22.333441+00:00 app[web.1]: #0 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/RegistersUsers.php(33): App\\Http\\Controllers\\Auth\\RegisterController->create()

2020-04-16T17:14:22.333645+00:00 app[web.1]: #1 [internal function]: App\\Http\\Controllers\\Auth\\RegisterController->register()

2020-04-16T17:14:22.333878+00:00 app[web.1]: #2 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(54): call_user_func_array()

2020-04-16T17:14:22.334184+00:00 app[web.1]: #3 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(45): Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller->callAction()

2020-04-16T17:14:22.334474+00:00 app[web.1]: #4 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(219): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch()

2020-04-16T17:14:22.335557+00:00 app[web.1]: #5 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(176): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->runController()

2020-04-16T17:14:22.336116+00:00 app[web.1]: #6 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(681): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->run()

2020-04-16T17:14:22.338228+00:00 app[web.1]: #7 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(130): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}()

2020-04-16T17:14:22.338467+00:00 app[web.1]: #8 /app/app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php(25): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()

2020-04-16T17:14:22.338749+00:00 app[web.1]: #9 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): App\\Http\\Middleware\\RedirectIfAuthenticated->handle()

2020-04-16T17:14:22.339085+00:00 app[web.1]: #10 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php(41): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()

2020-04-16T17:14:22.339422+00:00 app[web.1]: #11 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings->handle()

2020-04-16T17:14:22.339822+00:00 app[web.1]: #12 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(76): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()

2020-04-16T17:14:22.340187+00:00 app[web.1]: #13 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken->handle()

2020-04-16T17:14:22.340568+00:00 app[web.1]: #14 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()

2020-04-16T17:14:22.340927+00:00 app[web.1]: #15 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle()

2020-04-16T17:14:22.341294+00:00 app[web.1]: #16 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(56): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()

2020-04-16T17:14:22.341608+00:00 app[web.1]: #17 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handle()

2020-04-16T17:14:22.341958+00:00 app[web.1]: #18 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()

2020-04-16T17:14:22.342222+00:00 app[web.1]: #19 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle()

2020-04-16T17:14:22.342493+00:00 app[web.1]: #20 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(66): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()

2020-04-16T17:14:22.342730+00:00 app[web.1]: #21 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies->handle()

2020-04-16T17:14:22.343005+00:00 app[web.1]: #22 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(105): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()

2020-04-16T17:14:22.343257+00:00 app[web.1]: #23 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(683): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then()

2020-04-16T17:14:22.343550+00:00 app[web.1]: #24 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(658): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack()

2020-04-16T17:14:22.343820+00:00 app[web.1]: #25 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(624): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute()

2020-04-16T17:14:22.344110+00:00 app[web.1]: #26 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(613): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute()

2020-04-16T17:14:22.344402+00:00 app[web.1]: #27 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(170): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch()

2020-04-16T17:14:22.344779+00:00 app[web.1]: #28 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(130): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}()

2020-04-16T17:14:22.345146+00:00 app[web.1]: #29 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()

2020-04-16T17:14:22.345400+00:00 app[web.1]: #30 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle()

2020-04-16T17:14:22.345750+00:00 app[web.1]: #31 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()

2020-04-16T17:14:22.346005+00:00 app[web.1]: #32 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle()

2020-04-16T17:14:22.346308+00:00 app[web.1]: #33 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()

2020-04-16T17:14:22.346647+00:00 app[web.1]: #34 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle()

2020-04-16T17:14:22.347062+00:00 app[web.1]: #35 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(63): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()

2020-04-16T17:14:22.347431+00:00 app[web.1]: #36 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle()

2020-04-16T17:14:22.347714+00:00 app[web.1]: #37 /app/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php(57): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()

2020-04-16T17:14:22.348010+00:00 app[web.1]: #38 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies->handle()

2020-04-16T17:14:22.348359+00:00 app[web.1]: #39 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(105): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()

2020-04-16T17:14:22.348679+00:00 app[web.1]: #40 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(145): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then()

2020-04-16T17:14:22.349008+00:00 app[web.1]: #41 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(110): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter()

2020-04-16T17:14:22.349145+00:00 app[web.1]: #42 /app/public/index.php(55): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle()

2020-04-16T17:14:22.349168+00:00 app[web.1]: #43 {main}

2020-04-16T17:14:22.349170+00:00 app[web.1]: "}
```

it's seems Image is my issue but i can't find my answer and my app is updated (composer), can you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change composer.json file and add `"intervention/image": "dev-master"` to require section.

Then add below line to app.php in `$aliasses` section.

```
'Image' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class
```

Ps1: More detailed answer can be found on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27504070/6212294) by [Qamar Uzman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3588275/qamar-uzman)
.

Ps2: Another solution can be found on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37456051/6212294) by [Abhishek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3476207/abhishek).

Comment: i think it works but now new error, he can't write image data to path...

Comment: Are you trying to save some images on heroku?

Comment: yes, when i create an user he needs to save an profile picture. i know it's temporary but it's just a site for demonstration not a real site so i don't care and if i need i can remove that function but i want to understand this issue because everything work localy

Comment: It is recommended to use [spatie/mediaLibrary](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-medialibrary) package for assigning media to a class, and also use s3 driver for file storage: [laravel doc for file storate](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/filesystem#driver-prerequisites).

Comment: i know it's better but i'm a new dev and it's a little bit too much for me at the moment to change that and again it's not an issue if the picture is lost after, now i juste want my register works and save the picture for the session, not more